# How to apply a certain function to DataFrame column values on a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the df below:

```
ID     Value
 1        45
 2      -111

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Value'], data=[['1', '45'], ['2', '-111'])
```

How can I apply the np.radians() function to the Value column if and only if the current value does not equal -111?

Final output would be:

```
ID     Value
 1  0.785398
 2      -111
```

I am trying to do something like

```
df['Value'] = df.apply(lambda row: '-111' if row['Value'] == '-111' else np.radians(row['Value'].astype(float)), axis=1)
```

but am running into isssues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) as follows:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].where(df['Value'] == -111, np.radians(df['Value']))
```

[`.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) keeps the values of the series if the test condition is true and replace by the values of the second parameter if the test condition is false. Thus, it replace the values only when the value not equals -111 here.

Result:

```
print(df)


   ID       Value
0   1    0.785398
1   2 -111.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean-indexing:

```py
# convert Value column to float
df["Value"] = df["Value"].astype(float)

# create a mask
mask = df.Value != -111

# apply np.radians using the mask
df.loc[mask, "Value"] = df.loc[mask, "Value"].apply(np.radians)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  ID       Value
0  1    0.785398
1  2 -111.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.where` option:

```
df.Value = np.where(df.Value.ne(-111), radians(df.Value) , df.Value)
```

Full code:

```
from numpy import radians
df.Value = df.Value.astype(int)
df.Value = np.where(df.Value.ne(-111), radians(df.Value) , df.Value)
```